# multiple return statement in c++

Tags: c++, function, return

I have tried to complete a C++ exercise where you have to complete function definitions for a 'Golf' function and devise a program based on this however, I am having a problem with one of the functions.

Part of the goal of the function, wants you to return 1 if the user has entered a name for the golf player, and return 0 if no name is entered.

I am experiencing some difficulty with this, as when I run the program, I am always getting 1 returned to the main.

Underneath I have listed what I have done so far for each file:

**golf.h**

```
#ifndef GOLF_H
#define GOLF_H

const int Len = 40;

struct golf {
    char fullname[Len];
    int handicap;
};

void setgolf(golf &g, const char *name, int hc);
int setgolf(golf &g);
void handicap(golf &g, int hc);
void showgolf(const golf &g);

#endif  /* GOLF_H */
```

**golf.cpp**

```
#include "golf.h"
#include "iostream"

void setgolf(golf &g, const char *name, int hc) {


    strcpy(g.fullname, name);
    g.handicap = hc;

}

int setgolf(golf &g) {


    std::cout << "Golfer's name:";
    std::cin.getline(g.fullname, Len);
    if (std::cin.get() == '\0')
        return 0;


    std::cout << "Golfer's handicap: ";
    std::cin >> g.handicap;


    return 1;

}

void handicap(golf &g, int hc) {
    g.handicap = hc;
    std::cout << g.fullname << "'s new handicap is:" << g.handicap;

}

void showgolf(const golf &g) {

    std::cout << "Player's Name:" << g.fullname << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Player's handicapped:" << g.handicap << std::endl;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "golf.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int retuVal = 0;

    golf ann;
    setgolf(ann, "Ann Birdfree", 24);
    showgolf(ann);
    cout << "\n";


    golf peter;
    retuVal = setgolf(peter);
    cout<<"return value is:"<<retuVal<<endl;


    cout << "\nGolf details reset in new handicap\n";
    handicap(peter, 5);

    cout << "\nDetails reprinted";
    showgolf(peter);

return 0;
}
```

Please let me know, what it is that I have done wrong, so that I can return 0 instead of returning 1 all of the time.

Thanks Jis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `setgolf` remove the following code:

```
if (std::cin.get() == '\0')
return 0;
```

and instead write...

```
if(strlen(g.fullname)==0)
   return 0;
```

This is because when the user doesn't want to enter a name he just hits the enter key. This makes the string empty, since `getline` fills the character array until it is completely filled or it sees a `newline` character in the stream. So, if we just check its length, whether its greater than `0`, then its enough. for furthur reference about `getline` see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)

Answer (score 1):

The probability of `cin.get()` returning `'\0'` is almost 0.
(If `cin` is connected to a terminal, it can only happen if the
user enters a control-@.) Maybe you want to return 0 if the user
enters an empty string?

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do - return 0 if the user enters an empty string. Thanks for the insight into what cin.get() cannot do.